# Clearing HTTP Basic Auth using a web extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a web extension that displays a badge as a 'page action' when you are logged in using HTTP Basic auth.

When clicked, I would to automatically log the user out. I can't seem to find an API that allows me to clear the HTTP Basic auth cache. Does such an API exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross browser client-side method for "logging out" of an authorized resource. To do it securely, you really need to delete the auth/session info on the server side so the server no longer recognizes it.

This isn't something you can do inside the browser.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'm developing a web extension, not just a standard webapp. I'm also less interested in a an approach that works literally everywhere. If there's an api that works in a single browser I'm fine.